# How to prevent selected UIButton from changing to normal image when touching down?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have two images for a UIButton. In its notmal state, it's a pencil. When I select it, it's a paper. But right when I **touch down** it shows the pencil even though I haven't selected it yet. How can I prevent this?

```
@IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    btn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Pencil").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    btn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Paper").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .selected)
    btn.tintColor = .cyan

    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchedButton), for: .touchUpInside)

}

func touchedButton() {
    if !btn.isSelected {
        btn.isSelected = true

    } else {
        btn.isSelected = false
        }



}
```

Comment: What is the event that you have dragged your `IBAction` for? Is it `touchUpInside`?

Comment: Ohh.. i'm not sure. I'm not very familiar with storyboards so I just dragged the button on my code. Could it possibly be that there's a default dragging target method ?

Comment: By default it is set to `IBOutlet` when you control + drag in swift from storyboard. Just do it again and make sure that inside the pop up that comes up, it is set to `IBAction` and **not** `IBOutlet` and the event is `touchUpInside`

Answer (score 0):

u can use highlighted sate of UIButton for example, set image for highlighted state also,

```
btn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: 
            "Paper").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .highlighted)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. When I press down the button showing the pencil, it shows the paper highlighted. The problem is when it's selected (showing paper) and begin pressing down, the pencil shows until I drag away.